# Can user's geolocation be accessed only via cell or wifi?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Cordova mobile application that needs to access the user's location to know if the user is close to an object or not. I'm using cordova-plugin-geolocation and I get the geolocation if GPS is turned on.

Since Google and such providers can access your location by WiFi or by cell signal I wonder if it is possible to get the user's location without turning the GPS on? 
I'd like to have a scenario like this: When user's GPS is turned on, the location info is more accurate, but when accessing via cell or WiFi the location is maybe not so accurate, but still usable. 
Turning GPS on and off can be annoying that's why I'd like to provide an option that works without turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't a direct way in Cordova to detect if the location is from a GPS source, you can work around it.

Geolocation returns a `Coordinates` from which you can see that, if the location is acquired from WiFi or cellular source, `altitude` will be null, along with in some cases `speed` also null.

This check along with `accuracy < 10~20` should ideally conclude that the location is from GPS.

Comment: Thanks, that's a valid point, but if I understand correctly the GPS must still be enabled and accuracy provides you the information from which source the coordinates have been acquired?